# stream video from Raspberry PI to native iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3

I am wondering if there is a way to stream video from Raspberry Pi to a native iOS app.

I am NOT asking if it's possible to stream over a web server since I already know how to do that. However, if there is a way to capture the stream from the web and display it in a native iOS application without being directed to Quicktime or Safari that will work fine. E.g. if stream is playing on 192.168.0.1:8080 to display that inside my iPhone app.

I am currently working on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with a Raspberry Pi camera module with Xcode 8.0 (beta) and Swift 3.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it by using ffmpeg to decode the compressed video frame by frame via OpenCV. Integrating it all is tricky, but the combination works. See the tutorials on the OpenCV web site.

Answer (score 0):

I currently did it with this :

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {




    @IBOutlet weak var player_View: UIView!

     var playerControllerView: UIView!

    var player:AVPlayer?;
    let LOW_URL = URL(string:YOUR_STREAM_URL)!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        self.player = AVPlayer(url: LOW_URL)
        player?.currentItem!.add(videoOutput)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = self.player
        self.playerControllerView = playerController.view;
        self.playerControllerView.layoutMargins.left = 0;
        self.playerControllerView.layoutMargins.top = 0;
        self.player_View.addSubview(self.playerControllerView)
        playerController.view.frame = self.player_View.bounds


        self.player?.play()



    }
```

`player_View` is bound to a UIView in the storyboard.